# Angular angular-ui-router access error angular 1.6.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to reject access to a view if no cookie is set, I keep getting same errors in my console on reject. resolve works fine but reject gives errors.  I have looked around and found a few threads and answers but non have yet helped some said this problem was fixed in 1.61 but im still getting it.

**My code**

```
 .state('form.mockup', {
        url: '/mockup',
        templateUrl: 'views/form-mockup.html',
        resolve: {
            "check": ['$q', '$cookies', '$location', function($q, $cookies, $location) {
                if ($cookies.get('UserName')) { //cookie to check
                    console.log("logged in");
                    return $q.resolve({});
                } else {
                    console.log("error no access");
                    return $q.reject('no access allowed');
                    $location.path('/form/upload');

                }
            }
        ]
        }
    })
```

**My error**

> Transition Rejection($id: 3 type: 6, message: The transition errored,
>   detail: no access allowed)
>     _defaultErrorHandler    @   angular-ui-router.min.js:13
>   (anonymous)   @   angular-ui-router.min.js:13
>   (anonymous)   @   angular.js:17000 $digest    @   angular.js:18182
>   $apply    @   angular.js:18480 (anonymous)    @   angular.js:20397
>   e @   angular.js:6362 (anonymous) @   angular.js:6642
>
> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"$id":3,"type":6,"message":"The
>   transition errored","detail":"no access allowed"}
>   (anonymous)   @   angular.js:14642 (anonymous)    @   angular.js:11102
>   g @   angular.js:17028 $digest    @   angular.js:18182
>   $apply    @   angular.js:18480 (anonymous)    @   angular.js:20397
>   e @   angular.js:6362 (anonymous) @   angular.js:6642

Comment: don't you need to inject the dependencies for your "check" resolve function ? `"check": ['$q', '$cookies', '$location', function($q, $cookies, $location) {}]`

Comment: well if you need your dependences, just copy the signature of the function i wrote

Comment: yep sorry. need more coffee. thank you will try

Comment: no problem, that make two of us ! haha

Comment: nice, thanks for that I did not know that. saves some code ! plus1